# How to save selected dropdown list item to database table in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have already bind dropdownlist from another table. But as because i am doing registration page so that i need to get the selected item text to save into my registration table.I am very new to ASP.net MVC so please help somebody. Thank you

I am providing my drop-down bind code, then after what to do i don't know.

in controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            employee_databaseEntities2 db = new employee_databaseEntities2();
            ViewBag.User_Demo = new SelectList(db.City_table, "cityid", "cityname");
            return View();
        }
```

in view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("User_Demo", "Select City")
```

And this HttpPost Index code is my code to insert other fields in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(ValidateClass vc)
        {            
            string query = "insert into userReg values('" + vc.username + "','" + vc.age + "','" + vc.email + "','" + vc.password + "','" + vc.repassword + "','" + vc.gender + "','" + vc.cityname + "')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ViewData["Message"] = "Inserted Successfully";
            con.Close();
            return View();
        }
```

Here in vc.Cityname i need that dropdown value.
ValidateClass is my model name.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow!
The name of your html elements have to be the same as your model class to bind correctly. You should change `User_Demo` to `cityname` in your code.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            employee_databaseEntities2 db = new employee_databaseEntities2();
            ViewBag.cityname = new SelectList(db.City_table, "cityid", "cityname");
            return View();
        }
```

Your html code

```
 @Html.DropDownList("cityname", "Select City")
```

Please consider using an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) for connecting to your database to prevent sql injection attacks.

Comment: I have changed @Html.DropDownList("User_Demo", "Select City")  to                  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.cityname, ViewBag.User_Demo as SelectList, "--Select City--").    But i need the selected text from dropdownlist to insert into my database table..

Comment: @Chandan thats Ok! after changing, `vc.cityname` should be the value of selected item in dropdown.